# Default row on multicomponent UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, function

The application tracks the distance traveled on a given car, based on user input the current odometer value on a UIPickerView. I have been able to construct it, with 6 components and row values range from 0 to 9. Shown in the image:

[PickerView Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1VN4.png)

I want it to be able to show the last tracked distance as default row selected, when the PickerView appears.  The last tracked distance is stored on a Int type var (lastDistance).

I was able to loop through each digit on the distance based on a custom extension for Int. (lastDistance.digits : [Int]). Also loop through each component. But don't know the proper way to select the correct component for digit in lastDistance.

The components array is always: components=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

For example if value is 4400 Miles. The digits array is [4, 4, 0, 0] and the correct selection for this distance should be:

```
pickerView.selectRow(lastDistance.digits[0], inComponent: components[2], animated: false)
pickerView.selectRow(lastDistance.digits[1], inComponent: components[3], animated: false)
pickerView.selectRow(lastDistance.digits[2], inComponent: components[4], animated: false)
pickerView.selectRow(lastDistance.digits[3], inComponent: components[5], animated: false)
```

Problem is when distance varies from 2 to 6 digits the components selected should change.

Comment: You said "Problem is when distance varies from 2 to 6 digits the components selected should change." I don't understand what that means. Are you talking about dealing with leading zeros in your values? If you picker has 6 components, why don't you have code to set all 6 components (`inComponent` values ranging from 0 to 5)?

Comment: If it is 2 digits just show 0 in the first 4? Also why do you have components array?

Comment: The components array never change is always 6 components but distance digits array is always changing from car to car or from time to time.  I can’t set it statically should be set with a for loop or something alike

Comment: @DuncanC Yes I meant about dealing with leading 0s, and doing dynamically because this is set on "CarDetailViewController" viewDidLoad, so each time user clicks on a car list that VC is called, and each car on that list would have different values for the default picker view row